# Can't pop UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a `UIImagePickerController` with a custom overlay. I am trying to implement a cancel button that will just pop the `UIImagePickerController`. My code for the setup is below:

```
- (void)tapPhoto {

    //setup the picker
    self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.picker.delegate = self;
    self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.picker.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    self.picker.showsCameraControls=NO;

    self.cameraOverlay = [[CameraOverlay alloc] init];
    UIImage *camoverlayImage = self.cameraOverlay.cameraOverlayImage;
    UIImageView *camoverlayImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:camoverlayImage];
    camoverlayImageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.cameraOverlay.previewSize.width , self.cameraOverlay.previewSize.height);

    //init the control view
    UIView *cameraControls= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
    [cameraControls addSubview:camoverlayImageView];

    //Shutter Button
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];//70*70
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cameraoff"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cameraon"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2)-70/2, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-70-10, 70 , 70);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(takePhoto) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cameraControls addSubview:button];


    UIButton *button2 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [button2 setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelPhoto) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(5, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height-30, 0, 0);
    [button2 sizeToFit];
    [cameraControls addSubview:button2];

    [self.picker setCameraOverlayView:cameraControls];
    [self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

-(void)cancelPhoto{

    NSLog(@"photo canceled");
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.picker animated:YES];



}

-(void)takePhoto{
    //this will auto trigger the control
    [self.picker takePicture];
}
```

I am trying to pop it from the navigation controller but not having any luck. I have also tried `[self.picker popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`. Could anyone give me any pointers on why this isn't working? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are (correctly) presenting your picker:

```
[self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

The opposite of `present` is not push or pop, but `dismiss`:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

*First this line is wrong!*

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.picker animated:YES];
```

*Why you are pushing the picker, when  your picker is already presented in your current view controller*

**The correct method is this:-**

```
-(void)cancelPhoto{

      //as you have presented the view controller so have dismiss it by this way. 
     [self.picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this-

```
-(void)tapPhoto {
   //set up the Picker
    self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.picker.delegate = self;
    self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.picker.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;

   //add a UIView as CameraOverLay   
      UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:picker.view.frame];
     [self.picker setCameraOverlayView:overlayView];

    //Present the Picker 
     [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This way, you should have a cancel button by default. Then just implement the delegate method and dismiss the controller when you hit on the cancel button.

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

      //get the captured image if any
    if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0)
            == kCFCompareEqualTo){
        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

       //save the image in photo library
       UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
    }

     //pop out or remove the picker
     [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to use `popViewControllerAnimated`. Instead try:

```
[self.picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```